# Discord-Bot is not joining my voicechannel

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot is not joining the voicechannel when i call the joinVoiceChannel() function. There are also no error messages or anthing further.

```
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel(
            {
                channelId: msg.member.voice.channel,
                guildId: msg.member.voice.guild.id,
                adapterCreator: msg.member.voice.guild.voiceAdapterCreator

            });
```

Comment: Did you check that the code is actually being run?

Comment: Yes, i have a console.log() statement right below this code and it gets executed

Comment: One thing to check is to make sure that the bot has the correct privileges on discord to join VC.

Comment: Already checked, the bot has admin privileges on my discord server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```